# Author name and year not displayed with Harvard referencing style?

Tags: citing, natbib

I use the below given code for getting  Harvard style of citation. I have used the package `natbib` and used  `\bibliographystyle{agsm}`. I get Harvard style in reference section. However, in the body of the document, it cites as "[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrsdW.png)" instead of the required author year format. I am not able to fix it. Please share your thoughts regarding the possible error.

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\begin{document}
This is a test doc \cite{testref}.
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Please see the results
[image]

And with the following change I get name in text but with extra bracket [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrsdW.png) and no year as shown below

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\begin{document}
This is a test doc \citet{testref}.
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
%\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `elsarticle` class already loads `natbib`. By default `natbib` is loaded with the `numbers` option and thus produces numeric citations. For author-year citations you can load `elsarticle` with the `authoryear` option.

[The `elsarticle` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/doc/elsdoc.pdf) explains in §11 *Bibliography* (p. 13)

> `natbib` package is loaded by `elsarticle` with `numbers` as default option. You can change this to author-year or harvard scheme by adding option `authoryear` in
>   the class loading command. If you want to use more options of the `natbib` package, you can do so with the `\biboptions` command, which is described in the section 4, *Usage*.

```
\documentclass[review,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
This is a test doc \citep{sarfraz}.

As \citet{sarfraz} found.

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is a test doc (Sarfraz and Razzak, 2002).//As Sarfraz and Razzak (2002) found.]

---

Note that `elsarticle` comes with its own set of `.bst` files. If you are planning to submit to an Elsevier journal (IMHO that is the only good reason for using the `elsarticle` class), I suggest you have a look at `elsarticle-harv` instead of `asgm` for author-year citations.

```
\documentclass[review,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
This is a test doc \citep{sarfraz}.

As \citet{sarfraz} found.

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is a test doc (Sarfraz and Razzak, 2002).//As Sarfraz and Razzak (2002) found.]